# How to run a Raspiban in QEMU

Tags: qemu, emulation, arm

How do you run a standard Raspbian image in QEMU?

I'm following the instructions in [this wiki](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/wiki), but the first step is failing.

I downloaded the kernal `kernel-qemu-4.1.13-jessie` and the [Raspbian Jessie Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) image, but when I run:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.1.13-jessie \
    -cpu arm1176 \
    -m 256 \
    -M versatilepb \
    -no-reboot \
    -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" \
    -hda 2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie-lite.img
```

A QEMU window pops up and seems to show it booting correctly, but then it says "rebooting in 1 second" and closes. My local terminal only outputs:

```
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_volume() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_mute() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

Why is it rebooting even though I'm using the `-no-reboot` option? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I didn't edit a few files in the image, as outlined [here](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/wiki/Emulating-Jessie-image-with-4.x.xx-kernel).

Once I did that, it booted fine.